# Getting Bootstrap 4 Navbar Sidebar to Extend to Full Height of Page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am working with Bootstrap 4 for the first time in a .NET MVC (Not Core) starter application. Bootstrap version updated to 4.1 within Nuget.

I need to have both a horizontal navbar at the top as well as a vertical navbar (sidebar) on the left side.

The example I have been working off of:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/dashboard/

The problem that I am having is that the sidebar only extends down as far as the main page content goes, I have been unable to get it to extend down to 100% of the page.  I have tried setting the height manually both on the navbar and sidebar related divs, but it has no effect.

_Layout.cshtml :

```
<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Company name</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
        <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="home"></span>
                            Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file"></span>
                            Orders
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span>
                            Products
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="users"></span>
                            Customers
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span>
                            Reports
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="layers"></span>
                            Integrations
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
                    <span>Saved reports</span>
                    <a class="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
                        <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span>
                    </a>
                </h6>                 
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">      
                @RenderBody()               
        </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>ASP.NET</h1>
<p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
<p><a href="https://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Getting started</h2>
        <p>
            ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
            enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
            for enjoyable, agile development.
        </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
        <p>You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How it looks (yellow line represents approx where I would expect the sidebar to extend down to):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a bit tricky one...
Bootstrap is using extra CSS to accomplish this Layout. It wouldn't work with Bootstrap only. They added a class ".sidebar":

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 48px 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

Here's a Code-Pen Example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRjmBN

I also added a 'overflow-y: auto' in case the content inside the sidebar gets to long.

Hope that helps!